# Oracle ORA-00979 - "not a GROUP BY expression"

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00979

Can anybody please help me with this particular query? I'm having ORA-00979 when trying to run this:

```
select   t0.title, count (1) as count0, (select   count (1)
      from contract c1, se se1
      where c1.c_id = se1.c_id
      and se1.svc_id = 3
      and se1.deleted = 0
      and c1.deleted = 0
      and c1.c_date between to_date ('07.10.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy') 
                        and to_date ('22.11.2010', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
      and c1.company = 0
      and c1.tdata.tariff = c0.tdata.tariff
    ) as count1
  from contract c0, se se0, tariff t0
  where c0.c_id = se0.c_id
  and se0.svc_id = 3
  and se0.deleted = 0
  and c0.deleted = 0
  and c0.c_date between to_date ('21.11.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy') 
                and to_date ('06.01.2011', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
  and c0.company = 0
  and t0.tariff_id = c0.tdata.tariff
  group by t0.title
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your subquery with the `select count(1)` part. Just because it's got a count in it doesn't actually make it an aggregate. It's still a subquery that will be applied to every row and as you can see it uses the value `c0.tdata.tariff` which is not part of the group.

Comment: Well said. grouping by c0.tdata.tariff could arrange things.

Comment: @Benoit -- but grouping on that additional column would change the overall query results.  Whereas adding a group function, SUM, around the scalar subquery would resolve the issue and total up the counts within the existing groups.

Comment: Thanks, that is answer for this particular question. But the better solution to the overall problem was presented here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605994/oracle-ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression/4606082#4606082

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that scalar subquery is causing the problem -- it is neither a group function, nor is it in the GROUP BY list.

Probably you could workaround it with something like:

```
select   t0.title, count (1) as count0, SUM(select   count (1) ...) AS count1
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering this seems to be two instances of the same query just over different dates (I might be wrong here...it's been a long day), you could probably just simplify it and rewrite like this:

```
select
  t0.title, 
  count (case when c0.c_date between to_date ('21.11.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy') 
                and to_date ('06.01.2011', 'dd.mm.yyyy') then 1 end) as count0,
  count (case when c0.c_date between to_date ('07.10.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy') 
                and to_date ('22.11.2011', 'dd.mm.yyyy') then 1 end) as count1
from 
  contract c0, 
  se se0, 
  tariff t0
where 
  c0.c_id = se0.c_id
  and se0.svc_id = 3
  and se0.deleted = 0
  and c0.deleted = 0
  and (c0.c_date between to_date ('21.11.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy') 
                and to_date ('06.01.2011', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
    or c0.c_date between to_date ('07.10.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy') 
                        and to_date ('22.11.2010', 'dd.mm.yyyy'))
  and c0.company = 0
  and t0.tariff_id = c0.tdata.tariff
group by t0.title
```

Comment: That is great solution, thank you! I did not know it is possible to solve the problem like that, it is also solves "zeroes" problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your group by needs to include all of the non-aggregate columns from your select list. In this case, the group by is missing the `count1` returned by your subquery.